# Package Structure In Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

I have created a maven project on my Mac using Eclipse. My package structure comes in a folder and its hard for me to create a java class. Packages also do not show up.

How can I fix it? tried googling no solution? please help.

Comment: I do not understand your question. A Maven project has a standard folder structure, e.g. you put your Java sources into `src/main/java`, your resources into `src/main/resources` etc.

Comment: About your edit: You do not use Java packages in `src/test/resources` because this folder is not for Java code.

Comment: I am writing Selenium Codes. Still same issue in other src/main/resourses. Package not coming up in class file

Comment: Java test classes should go in `src/test/java`, though if the entire project consists of tests then putting everything in `src/test/java` is likely ok too.